# Type check React component props with Typescript in VS Code

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to get type checking of props on my component when using typescript.

I have defined this component:

import React from 'react'; // we need this to make JSX compile

```
interface CardProps {
  title: string,
  paragraph: string
}

export const Card = (props: CardProps) => (
  <aside>
    <h2>{ props.title }</h2>
    <p>
      { props.paragraph }
    </p>
  </aside>
)
```

When I try to use the component with wrong props, I want VS Code to give me an error:

```
<Card something={false} />
```

As you can see here, VS Code doesn't complain.  Typescript validation works for regular type checks, like `const test: number = "Hello"`.

[image]

Comment: Should work out of the box. Are you in a tsx file ?

Comment: Works in playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwCwAUI48AHYxZQF5ZwDCyKABMACsTDoA3ozhwYwGABssALjioYUNgHMANDLhhBybVGRgAFmo1bW2xgF9mDLAA9IsOLgisN-QUJwALxwABRg4qhqAsJiEBIAlMEAfGEGADxowEJYyQay6RYATMmShpEAdPJKvA7pAPTFeQyyBWDNra1lEfGoFUZmpuYWcE4trQ3tGfVZOc0JzsrwUMFhSUGp6TGBqCRYMBY6QZLciqhYDnD1yUA

Comment: I think it's because I have `Card` and `CardProps` defined in a external file that I import with `import Card from './Card'`, if I copy and paste everything to the same file, it works. So how can I export it properly from a file? Maybe that `CardProps` is not visible to the file importing the component.

Comment: @eivindml And don't you get an error on the import ? It should work fine regardless of file

Comment: One addition info, I have defined `Card` in a subfolder, inside a `index.tsx` file. Everything works if I import it like: `import { Card } from './Card/index'`. But wish I could just do `'./Card'`.

Comment: Typescript says it "Cannot find module ./Card", but it works, and the path is correct. The error goes away if I explicitly imports "./Card/index".

Comment: Trust me, it's not ESLint.

Comment: I tried, your scenario, assuming the `Card` is in a folder `Card` in a file `index.tsx`

Comment: I think the issue is that I'm using absolute paths for imports. I have `resolve: {  modules: [ path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), ] }` in webpack, which explains why it compiles, but can't get vs code + tsconfig.json to cooperate. I have set `"baseUrl": "src",` in tsconfig.